# Minimum separating subdivision in Plane

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Hi

I was thinking about the following problem:

Given a planar Graph embedded in the plane and a set of points $P$ contained in the faces (no face contains more than one point) I want to determine the maximum number of edges I can remove such that in the reduced graph no two points are contained in the same face.

Although I didn't find any publications considering this problem, I guess this must have been studied before.

Any pointers would be helpful to me.

If $P$ only consists of two points $p,q$ it is easy since, we can just compute the shortest cycle containing either $p$ or $q$ but not both in its face.

Thank you

Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to (a version of) [minimum $k$-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) AKA multiway cut. It seems that the general problem is solvable is polynomial time for any fixed $k$, but NP-complete for arbitrary $k$, even restricted to planar graphs. However, [Mohammadhossein Bateni, MohammadTaghi Hajiaghayi, Philip Klein, Claire Mathieu](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/claire/Publis/multiwaycut.pdf) give Polynomial time approximation schemes for the planar case.

Comment: @Ori: Could you please sketch the equivalence of the stated problem to min $k$-cut?  I don't doubt you, but it is not obvious to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: Here is a dual version of the question: we are given a planar graph with $k$ marked vertices and we want a minimum-sized set of edges that, when removed, disconnects the marked vertices from each other.

I think this is what Ori had in mind.

Comment: @Louis: Thanks! What I didn't see is the marking, but now I understand that also separating marked vertices falls under the same umbrella as just separating into $k$ components.

Comment: @Louis+@Joe: I don't see how this is equivalent (since we have the $k$ marked vertices, we don't have the choice of what the connected components are, which should make the problem easier.

Comment: I did write "(a version of) minimum $k$-cut". If you look at wikipedia it explicitly mention this version: "It is also NP-complete if we specify k vertices and ask for the minimum k-cut which separates these vertices among each of the sets". Also, the paper I linked deals with this version: "a multiway cut (also called a multi-terminal cut) problem asks for a subset of edges with minimum total length and whose removal disconnects each terminal from the others".

Comment: @Ori: Oh, OK, that's what one gets for skimming...

Answer (score 4):

Well, since your graph is planar, your question is really about the dual graph $H=G^*$ (whose vertices are the faces of your graph). Some vertices of $H$ (corresponding to faces with points in them) are marked red, the others blue, and you are asking how many edges of $H$ you can collapse without identifying two red vertices.

Firstly, no edge joining two red edges can be collapsed. So remove all such edges to get a new graph $H^\prime.$

Secondly, all edges connecting two blue vertices in $H^\prime$ can be collapsed. So do it, and obtain a new graph $H^{\prime \prime}.$

Now, you are asking how many edges in $H^{\prime \prime}$ can be collapsed. Such a collection is a maximal matching between the blue and the red sets in $H^{\prime \prime}.$ Finding such is well understood, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Comment: @Igor Rivin :Thank you for your answer. Your write: "Secondly, all edges connecting two blue vertices in H′ can be collapsed. So do it, and obtain a new graph H′′." Is this true? Because if i have a rectangle which is horizontaly divided into 3 parts l,m,r. The left division is made by a single vertical edge e, and the right one is done by a vertical path of come length c, and i have a point s in r and a point t outside of the rectangle, then the smallest separating arrangement would contain only 6 edges, but if i collapse
 any edge connecting two blue vertices i would thusby delete the edge e

Comment: and would end up with a solution of size 8.

Comment: Hmmm... I will ponder... 

Comment: @Igor: This is probably redundant, but we don't need to have a non-simple dual or any other such messiness to make examples where greedily discarding blue-blue edges is bad.

Start with a triangulation with a marked triangle.  Now take another such triangulation, and glue it in to the first one along a triangle not incident to either of the marked faces.  Repeat this a bunch of times to get a kind of "generalized stacked polytope".  The edges we want to keep are just the separating triangles in the graph we constructed, but those are all going to be blue-blue in the dual.

Comment: @Louis: I am sure that is true, but that does not answer the question of how to fix the algorithm, alas. 

Comment: @Igor: The point is that for $k=2$ this is just the $s-t$ minimum cut. Intuitively, you want to do a series of random contractions, keeping multiple edges but not loops, and hope that the distribution gets you close. (A kind of approximate Karger algorithm.)

Answer (score 3):

This is my interpretation of *andy*'s example in his comment to Igor's answer.
$s$ and $t$ are the green points.
Imagine the outer face red because it contains a (green) point.
$L$ and $M$ are blue because they contain no points.

 
[image: Separating Arrangement]

Removing $e$ would lead to a less efficient separator.

Comment: Wouldn't you want one more vertex on that path? As it's drawn they both remove 6 edges. /nitpick

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke Yes this is exactly the example I was thinking about, thank you very much for the picture. Do you know anything about this problem?
@Michael Biro  Yes one more vertex on the path would make the counterexample even more clear.


Comment: @Michael & andy: Added a vertex on the vertical path---Thanks for the correction.